# python -v doesn't just show the version but a lot of text

Tags: python, command-line

I have played around trying to install a virtual environment and now I get the weird feedback when trying to check which version of python I have installed. However python 3. code still runs.

Does anyone know what the problem here is?

```
tobi@derGeraet:~/Dokumente$ python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<A lot more import statements in between>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Comment: Use `python -h` to see the meaning of all command line parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python version is obtained by running `python -V`
From `python --help`

```
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
-V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
```

Comment: Great. Now it works. Thank you all!

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Just did. All the best :)

Comment: You actually accepted someone else's (Steven Kneiser) answer , not mine :)

Comment: Upps sorry. I am new to the community and thought you could accept more than one answer. Now it should be yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

No need to be fancy.  Always play it safe:

```sh
$ python --version
```

Comment: and in case of python 3 `python3 --version`